# Find best submatrix with least sum of differences between max element and other elements of size x*y of large matrix a*b

Tags: algorithm

Given a matrix A*B , find the min sum of differences between max element and other elements of all possible submatrixes of size XY

eg

```
2 3 4

5 6 1
```

for submatrix of sizes 2*2

```
2 3
5 6

max = 6
sum of diffs = |6-2|+|6-3|+|6-5|+|6-6|
             = 8


 3 4
 6 1
 max =6
sum of diff = |6-3|+|6-4|+|6-6|+|6-1|
            = 10
```

ans = 8 which is minimum

Surely brute force approach would be checking each possible submatrix and calculating diff between max and every element

Comment: Please show your attempts what you have done.